# TCL_Expect:: How to append /save "expect_out(buffer)" into a file continuously

Tags: tcl, expect

My TCL/Expect script:

```
foreach  data $test url $urls {
    send "test app website 1\r"
    expect "*#"
    send "commit \r"
    expect "*#"
    after 2000
    exec cmd.exe /c start iexplore.exe $url
    after 3000
    exec "C:/WINDOWS/System32/taskkill.exe" /IM IEXPLORE.EXE /F
    send "show application stats $data\r"
    expect "*#"
    expect "?" {
        puts [open urllist.txt w] $expect_out(buffer)
    }

 }
```

The above script is working fine except storing the output of $expect_out(buffer) into a file.

I want to send $expect_out(buffer) output to "urllist.txt" file continuously.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following trace procedure writes the value of expect_out (buffer) to a file specific to the spawn id.

```
proc log_by_tracing {array element op} {
    uplevel {
            global logfile
            set file $logfile($expect_out(spawn_id))
            puts -nonewline $file $expect_out(buffer)
     }
}
```

The association between the spawn id and each log file is made in the array logfile which contains a pointer to the log file based on the spawn id. Such an association could be made with the following code when each process is spawned.

```
spawn <some_app_name_here>
set logfile($spawn_id) [open exp_buffer.log w]
```

The trace has to be added in the code as

```
trace variable expect_out(buffer) w log_by_tracing
```

Internally, the `expect` command saves the `spawn_id` element of expect_out after the `X, string` elements but before the `buffer` element in the `expect_out` array. For this reason, the trace must be triggered by the buffer element rather than the spawn_id element.

**Note :** If you are not bother about much of spawned process or using only one spawned process or no spawned process at all, there is a simple way of doing the same, then it would be much easy.

Consider the following example.

```
proc log_by_tracing {array element op} {
    uplevel {
            puts -nonewline $file $expect_out(buffer)
     }
}

set file [ open myfile.log w ]
trace variable expect_out(buffer) w log_by_tracing

set timeout 60
expect {
       quit { exit 1 }
       timeout { exp_continue }
}
```

If you run the code, whatever you type in console till you type 'quit', the program will run and eventually it will be recorded in the file named `'myfile.log'`

You can simply add the proc `log_by_tracing` and the trace statement into your code.  Remember with this simple way, only one instance of expect_out(buffer) can be saved.

Reference : [trace](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm), [uplevel](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.htm) & [EXploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)